# Reliable client saving to disk in zeromq

Tags: zeromq

There is Request-Reply in ZeroMQ and there is a Titanic pattern which is about saving messages to disk. From my understanding `Clients` are reliable, but NOT in the way of saving to disk. Client always could crash and lose some data.

I have an idea to move that saving to disk, from `broker` in Titanic pattern, to Client. Client's reliability will be extended, so will be not needed on broker side.

Question is what are possible problems with such design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of past high-tech projects went into this territory due to a trouble with a need to avoid any appearance of a blocking `DiskIO` operation on a limited localhost device and the solution has led to a distributed mode of operations with a Control Plane and a Consolidation Plane services built atop of the cloud of distributed logging units.

While the motivation was different, the experience may help you on this given task.

If I may bring a few tips for you, these two would be the most important ones. Having this pair done, the rest is much better manageable and much more straightforward to get the job done both well and fast:

---

### First, DEFINE a List Of Requirements

**Without** a known target, **any** road leads "*there*".

State both must-have(s) and nice-to-have(s).

For each item qualify the required PASS/FAIL performance metrics

<kbd>Example</kbd>

**Any `DiskIO` operation is allowed to be executed with less than 200ms time-delay / skew since `aRemoteEventMessageArrivalTIME`.**

<kbd>Example</kbd>

**Whenever `aNumberOfAliveLoggingAGENTs` becomes less than `aProfileSpecifiedREDUNDANCY`, trigger `aRedundancyALARM`**

Do not hesitate to spend "a lot" time on doing this thoroughly well. Late *add-on*(s) may completely devastate your time-plan and make your previous work useless and/or hazardous to re-use in ad-hoc "extended" ( understand as "a-too-late added feature the original design/architecture decisions were absolutely not aware of" ) version.

---

### Second, DISAMBIGUATE what the "Reliable" means for your Project

Good news is, that Theoretical Cybernetics confirms, that one may design and operate a reliable system based on un-reliable components.

Bad news is, that you have to design-in the complex fault-resilience from scratch, bottom-up, to make it happen.

So, be carefull, what is really a must-have and what is possible to leave out as nice-to-have, in order to have your Project goal achievable within both a reasonable time & budget.

---

**Nota Bene**: Remember Pieter HINTJENS' remarks on reliability in his great book